# Scala can not access field

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala Class:

```
class Component(val node:Int, var start:Int, var c_size:Int)
```

I instantiate it like this:

```
var comp = new Component(1, 1, 1)
```

Then, I try to access one of its fields:

```
for(neighbour <- graph[comp.node]) ...
```

At this point however, I am getting an error:

> **error:** type node is not a member of Component

Why is the field not recognized?

Comment: Could you post the declaration or type of `graph`?

Comment: Try using graph(comp.node).

Comment: @Nyavro That was it.

Comment: This is one of the first things a Java programmer must forget. Scala does not use `[]` for array access.

Comment: Square brackets `[` and `]` are used for type parameters in Scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `graph` is declared as an array, you cannot access array elements using `[]`. Use `()` instead:

```
for(neighbour <- graph(comp.node))
```

The error is shown because Scala thinks you are trying to parameterize a `graph` method, with the type parameter being `comp.node`. This would be valid if there was such a method and `Component` had an inner type named `node`.